# A question about the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $h \in L^1(\mathbb{R}).$
Consider the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function defined as

$$h^*(b) = \sup_{t > 0}\frac{1}{2t}\int_{b-t}^{b+t}h.$$

Does it hold that $\{b\in \mathbb{R} : h^*(b) = \infty\}$ is a closed set?